# DecisionTree TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'str'

Tags: python, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

I am trying to understand `machine learning`, I picked up `DecisionTree` from `sklearn` as the first `algo` to try and understand.

```
X dataframe head:

    d_t_375  190dt375_std190MA
0  0.224533           0.143279
1  0.542533           0.095203
2 -0.238400           0.221700
3  0.167467           0.143120
4 -0.138533           0.076678

Y dataframe head:

  Entry buyorsell        pl
0     Y         B -0.224533
1     Y         B -0.350000
2     Y         S  0.950000
3     Y         B -0.167467
4     Y         S  1.300000

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test= train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3)
model = DecisionTreeClassifier()
model.fit(X_train,y_train)
```

I get an error

In `model.fit(X_train,y_train)`

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "site-packages/sklearn/tree/tree.py", line 801, in fit
>      X_idx_sorted=X_idx_sorted)
>    File "site-packages/sklearn/tree/tree.py", line 140, in fit
>      check_classification_targets(y)
>    File "site-packages/sklearn/utils/multiclass.py", line 168, in >check_classification_targets
>      y_type = type_of_target(y)
>    File "site-packages/sklearn/utils/multiclass.py", line 249, in >type_of_target
>      if is_multilabel(y):
>    File "/site-packages/sklearn/utils/multiclass.py", line 151, in >is_multilabel
>      labels = np.unique(y)
>    File "site-packages/numpy/lib/arraysetops.py", line 223, in unique
>      return _unique1d(ar, return_index, return_inverse, return_counts)
>    File "site-packages/numpy/lib/arraysetops.py", line 283, in _unique1d
>      ar.sort()
>   TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'str'

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: convert the `string` columns into `categorical`. I think that would solve your issue.

Comment: @AkshayNevrekar the `Y` and `B`/`S` columns? I tried dropping those columns and still get an error albeit different one.

Comment: Tried to convert to 'category' still the same error.